# Xcode 4.2 "Warning: the current language does not match this frame."

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

I'm writing a iOS app which uses audio input and output and am using parts of Apple's "Speak Here" code. In particular, I would to use the two classes **AQPlayer** and **AQRecorder**. These are written in Objective-C++ and have the files names AQPlayer.h, AQPlayer.mm, AQRecorder.h, and AQRecorder.mm.

The project complies without errors or warnings. When I try to run it, it pauses on the entry to either AQPlayer or AQRecorder (whichever I call first) and I get a message "Warning: the current language does not match this frame." Hitting the continue or step buttons just results in the the code stopping again.

Others who have seen this message fixed it by changing the extension on the file(s) to ".mm". My files have this extension and I'm still getting the problem.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps very lame, but I had similiar probs on mac which I fixed by adding:

`LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`

to my macbook in .bash_profile.